# I need to pass value of response into next request iteratively

Tags: jmeter

I have one response-1, I need to pass value X from response-1 to next request-2
Now From response-2 I will extract the value X and pass into request-3
Now From response-3 I will extract the value X and pass into request-4 ..... need to perform in a Loop.

```
Request-1 with "--"
    Response-1 > Extracted ValueX=a > Pass it to Request-2
Request-2 with "a"
    Response-2 > Extracted ValueX=d > Pass it to Request-3
Request-3 with "d"
    Response-3 > Extracted ValueX=asdf > Pass it to Request-4
.....
........
Till Request-100....
```

[image]

I did above request-response setup but on Req-2 and Req-3 it passes the same response repeatedly on Req-2 and Req-3.
i.e Here request-1 with "--" is fixed. From Response-1 we get Value=X and from response-2 we get Value=Y then it repeatedly executes 2&3 requests for loop of 100.

What I want is I don't want to write 100 request I need to write only one request and it post-Process the response of Previous one and perform till 100 requests.

Can anyone help how shall I pass this loop in jmeter.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can extract the value using a suitable [Post-Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors), for example:

   - for JSON: [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) or [JSON JMESPath Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_JMESPath_Extractor)
   - for HTML: [CSS Selector Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/cssjquery-extractor)
   - for XHTML and XML: [XPath Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor) or [XPath2 Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath2_Extractor)
   - for getting the value between two boundaries: [Boundary Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Boundary_Extractor)
   - for anything else: [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor)
2. If responses are different or have different structure - place the Post-Processor as a child of the respective request. Otherwise put it at the same level as all requests. See [Scoping Rules](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules) user manual entry for more details
3. Replace the value you need to replace with the JMeter Variable coming from the Post-Processor.
4. Loop can be defined either on [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) level or you can add a [Loop Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller) and put your requests under it.

The process is known as **[correlation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start)** and there is a lot of information on it in the Internet

Comment: I have edited my question for better understanding. What I want is I don't want to write 100 request I need to write only one request and it post-Process the response of Previous one and perform till 100 requests.